# You do not have sufficient permission for type: Product. Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have overridden Product 'listview' and get `You do not have sufficient permission for type: Product.` pop up. Any suggestion what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add principal for modification like below:

```
<context type="Customer" component="editor-area" merge-by="type" principal="asagentgroup,warehouseagentrole,warehousemanagerrole,admin">
```